# How to customize a generic type?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have an interface like this:

```
public interface BeanCreator<T> {   
   public T createBean();
   public Class<T> getClazz();
}
```

And I tried to customized it:

```
public class CustomizedBeanCreator<T> implements BeanCreator<T>{

    @Override
    public T createBean() {
        CustomizedBean bean = new CustomizedBean();
        bean.setId(-2323);
        bean.setName("this bean is created by a customized creator");       
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T t = (T)bean;      
        return t;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Class<T> getClazz() {
        return (Class<T>) CustomizedBean.class;
    }
}
```

Because of those two @SuppressWarnings, I feel uncomfortable.

What should I do to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the signature (and implementation) from

```
public class CustomizedBeanCreator<T> implements BeanCreator<T>{
```

to something like

```
public static class CustomizedBeanCreator implements BeanCreator<CustomizedBean> {

    @Override
    public CustomizedBean createBean() {
        CustomizedBean bean = new CustomizedBean();
        bean.setId(-2323);
        bean.setName("this bean is created by a customized creator");
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<CustomizedBean> getClazz() {
        return CustomizedBean.class;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class CustomizedBeanCreator implements BeanCreator<CustomizedBean> {
    @Override
    public CustomizedBean createBean() {
        CustomizedBean bean = new CustomizedBean();
        bean.setId(-2323);
        bean.setName("this bean is created by a customized creator");       
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<CustomizedBean> getClazz() {
        return CustomizedBean.class;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As [Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46739756/8041461) said, you will want to implement `BeanCreator<CustomizedBean>` instead of just `BeanCreator<T>`, the reason is the following:

```
@Override
public T createBean() {
    CustomizedBean bean = new CustomizedBean();
    bean.setId(-2323);
    bean.setName("this bean is created by a customized creator");       
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T t = (T)bean;      
    return t;
}
```

In this code you say you can return the type T, but you never say that  T is CustomizedBean, so the compiler cannot be sure that bean will be of type T, so the case is not safe

For example, you could ask for an instance of `CustomizedBeanCreator<String>`, and the compiler would expect `createBean()` to give back a String, and trying to cast a CustomizedBean to a String would cause a ClassCastException.